# insert into..on duplicate key with different column names

Tags: mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I have two tables `profieltest` and `parametertest`.

I want the `value` column in `profieltest` to be updated with the parameters from `parametertest` where the `user` id is the same and where the `field_id = 2` in `profieltest` . However if the combination between `user` and `field_id` in `profieltest` doesn't exist i want it to be inserted from `parametertest`.  i tried it with an on duplicate key statement with an unique key: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqfield ON profieltest (field_id, user)`, also `profieltest.id` is an auto increment value. I tried the following query but it gives me an error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 't1(t1.user, t1.field_id, t1.value) VALUES( id ,t1.user =
>   t2.user, t1.field_' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO profieltest t1(t1.user, t1.field_id, t1.value)
VALUES( id ,t1.user = t2.user, t1.field_id=2,  t1.value=t2.parameter)
  SELECT t2.user, t2.parameter
  FROM parametertest t2
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
  UPDATE  SET t1.value = t2.parameter    
  WHERE t1.User = t2.user
    AND t1.Field_id = 2
```

edit: added the error.

Comment: sorry, the error is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't1

(t1.user, t1.field_id, t1.value)

Values( , t2.user, 2,  t2.parameter) 
' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query worked for me:

```
INSERT INTO Profieltest ( field_id,  user, value )

SELECT field_id, User,  value
FROM parametertest
    WHERE   
    (field_id = 2
    OR field_id  =  6 
    OR field_id = 7)

On duplicate KEY UPDATE 
profieltest.value=(SELECT t2.value
  FROM parametertest t2
  WHERE t2.field_id =profieltest.field_id AND  t2.user=profieltest.user )
```